# Как заменить классы у элемента Jquery\Js

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть функция

```
function like(a, b) {
Ajax_Loading("");
$.getJSON(b.href, {}, function(b) {
    if (b.param == 0) {
        Alert_popup(b.data, lang[0][23][0])
    } else if (b.param == 1) {
        $("#message-" + a + " .postlike").replaceWith(b.linck);
        $(".likeBox-" + a).replaceWith(b.likeBlock)
    }
});
Ajax_close("")
```

};

Как добавить еще один класс помимо .postlike
в строку  $("#message-" + a + " .postlike").replaceWith(b.linck);
Чтобы ссылке добавлялось три класса при замене (replaceWith)

Comment: $("#message-" + a + " .postlike").replaceWith(b.linck).addClass("class1 class2");